# Question about a property of a plane?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

This is from *Kiselev's Geometry: Planimetry*, page 2:

> One can impose a plane on itself or any other plane in a way that takes one given point to any other given point, and this can also be done after flipping the plane upside down.

I'm not sure I really understand what this means. My interpretation is that at any time we can make a copy of any plane, make it coincide with the original plane (or make it parallel). Then we can take take any point in the copy and shift the copy so that that point lies on top of any other point in the original. But if we are talking about infinite planes with no axes, I'm not even sure how much sense it makes to talk about individual points; once the shifting is done, the final situation seems indistinguishable from the initial situation (unless we perhaps color some points, but this has not been mentioned).

Comment: Why do you need axes to have points? Synthetic geometry basically amounts to "there are points, some collections of points called lines, some collections of points called planes..." etc plus some other axioms.

Comment: There is, however, [pointless geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(geometry)#Geometry_without_points) but I don't know if this book is talking about that. Apparently not, given the language quoted.

Comment: @rschwieb Well doesn't talking about bijections presuppose that we have a method of identifying every point? Should I picture it this way? "I have two coinciding planes A and B. I can color any point in A red and any point in B yellow. I can always shift plane A so that the red point coincides with the yellow point."

Comment: I imagine you can formulate some mathematics with "spaces and arrows" with no mention of points, but I don't think that's what's going on here. Points must be assumed here. As soon as someone starts talking about putting one point onto another, then they're talking about points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it literally seems to say this

> There is a bijection between any two planes.

However, I wonder if it doesn't intend to say something richer like

> There is a bijective affine transformation between any two planes

or

> There is a distance preserving map between any two planes.

But this latter one at least requires a notion of distance, and I don't know the context of the book. Since the language is geometric ("flipping the plane") I suppose that the author is probably working with an ordered field, and that would make the last statement useful.

Comment: For the context of this book, this is a highschool euclidean geometry book from Russia

Comment: @Ovi OK. I think I'm safe then.

Comment: @Ovi Thanks god we didn't have such confusing textbooks in our time...

Comment: @Evgeny I have often wondered what it would have been like to live in the time when you learned about quaternions [directly from Hamilton's text](https://archive.org/details/elementsquaterni00hamirich).

Comment: @Evgeny Haha the preface says that this book was the standard in Russia from the 19th century to 1955.

Comment: @rschwieb Oh yeah, that wasn't an easy task, I presume :) Maybe it was more understandable in the context of Erlangen program and all these "wild experiments" with algebraic structures...